# Number a subset of entries based on current sorting

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, sorting

Is there a way to number a subset of entries in the attribute table based on the current sorting in Qgis?
e.g. select all entries with attribute X, sort them by abttribute Y, create a new column and fill the column (only for the selected and sorted values) whith 1 to n; not rownum or id.

Comment: I had to do the same but I just had to sort it by one ID and there were just two different values - so I copied it to a temporary table and then inserted it, so it was sorted and I could use `$rownum`. There is also an approach with using Calc http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41506/24484 but for me it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you might have a solution in QGIS 3.2 with a new feature added, thanks to Nyall Dawson (North Road). I haven't tried, but i guess oyou could try filtering the layer before running this new tool ?

> **Feature: Sort order option for "Add Incremental Field"**
>
> This change allows users to optionally set a sort order to use when assigning
> values in the Add Incremental Field algorithm. Previously values were
> always added using the original feature order. With this change users
> can control the order in which features are assigned values.

Comment: works like a charme, was exactly what i needed. particularly the "group values by" to define ordered groups!  thanks!

Comment: Happy to know it helped ! Thanks for your detailed comment on your usage.