# QGIS Zonal Statistics Crashing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics

I am trying to run zonal statistics to assign elevation to ungauged nodes (point data, 130000 points) across Ireland. I have converted the point data to a polygon to run the zonal statistics. When running the zonal statistics the QGIS project will shut down before finishing. I have tried this multiple times now and it shuts down each time. I'm thinking its because the ungauged nodes file is too large but I would like this output to be completed with the entire file.

Comment: I am not sure how to split it as all of the attributes are different and I don't want to split it into 130000 different subsets. Is there a different method? Thanks @BERA

Comment: Probably you need more RAM for your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split you layer into subsets then zonal stats using each split layer and merge all the outputs.

(I'm using a point layer just to show the workflow, you need to use your polygon layer)

1. Field calculate a Group integer field: `(@row_number-1)%100+1`. It will [create a field of repeating numbers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41504/how-to-add-a-sequence-to-the-attribute-table) from 1 to 100: 1,2,3 ..., 98, 99, 100, 1,2,3 ...

[image]

2. [Split Vector Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer) by the field to create 100 output vector layer with 1300 feature in each.
   [image]
3. Execute Zonal statistics in batch:
   [image]
4. Then [Merge](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgismergevectorlayers) the outputs

Comment: Doesn't the "Zonal statistics" processing algorithm need a polygon layer as input?

Comment: Yes, I just used the point layer to show the workflow